# Best way to dismiss a progress dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm developing my first Android application and I'm having a hard time dismissing a progress dialog via Broadcast.

The situation is quite simple: I have a login activity that uses a Service to communicate with the server and allow or reject the user. The progress dialog should show while the app waits for the server response, and be dismissed on response arrival. Every works great until my app is paused, because the activity doesn't receive the broadcast (as the filter was unregistered in the onPause event). 
So:

1. Activity shows the dialog and start the service.
2. The service sends authentication info to server and waits for
   response.
3. The user press Home while he waits for the response and the activity
   goes Paused.
4. The service receives the response from the server and broadcast the
   intent.
5. As the activity was paused didn't received the broadcast, therefore doesn't dismiss the progress dialog (wich normally is dismissed with no problem if the app receives the broadcast. And as my progress dialog is not cancelable it get stuck in the activity).

I know that while the receiver is unregistered, the activity won't execute the `onReceive` method (which is critical to me). I need to execute the method that dismisses the dialog and continue de log in process even if the app is on background, so when the user comes back it will be on the main page (if the log in is right). Or at least, when the activity is resumed executes the `onReceive` to process the response.

I though in one solution, but I'm not sure if is the best way to do it. I thought of besides sending the broadcast from the service, save the intent in the Application Context, and when the activity is resumed check if there is an intent in the context and use it like the service response (and dismissing the dialog in the process).

Obviously, the dialog is not the only thing that worries me, I need to execute all the section that dismisses the dialog because it decides whether to let the user in or reject the log in.

If anyone could help with some best practice for that situation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Generally you should **check** for some condition at start of your `Activity` to decide whether to display dialog or not. If condition is not met, then you're displaying dialog and still waiting for broadcast (or sending a new one, if it's required). In other case - you're just not displaying the dialog (as if it were dismissed).

Comment: great idea, i will implement it. So, when the activity is paused i dismiss the dialog, and when is resumed i show the dialog (if needed). But the problem is if by the time is resumed the broadcast was already sent and the activity don't receive the broadcast, then how can I give the activity the information to let the user in or reject him?

Comment: As I said - you should check at Activity startup, if it has missed broadcast. For example, you can save some flag in `SharedPreferences` while receiving broadcast and check if it is set in `Activity#onResume()`. So, you'll be able to know if you missed broadcast or not.